# crate name with hyphens not being recognized

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to practice rust using [exercism](http://exercism.io/)

one of problem set has a test file like this 
[image]

when i tried to run Cargo test, its not recognizing the crate name.I tried different variations difference-of-squares,"difference-of-squares" with no success.[image]

contents of Cargo.toml

[image]

edit: I tried with both stable release and the current nightly.

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Take the time to copy and paste the code into Stack Overflow. This helps for searching, and also allows for technology like screen readers to be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're likely using an old version of Cargo.  Previously, crates-with-hyphens were allowed, but horrible to use:

```
extern crate "difference-of-squares" as squares;
```

At some point in the past, Cargo was changed to basically not allow them; it just converted all hyphens to underscores so you didn't have to manually rename every crate that had hyphens in its name, every time you used it.

You haven't specified what version you're using, but updating to the latest release (Rust 1.2 <s>just got released</s> will be released in a few days) should fix it.  Failing that, try quoting the literal name of the crate.

Comment: These are the versions i'm using 
rustc 1.3.0-nightly (38517944f 2015-08-03)
cargo 0.4.0-nightly (1b902d4 2015-08-03) (built 2015-08-03)

When I tried to do 'extern crate "difference-of-squares" as squares', its still throwing an error: expected ident, found `"difference-of-squares"`

Comment: @BobLoblaw Well, I'm using the exact same release.  I recreated your problem from both what you listed and the code from that website, and I don't have your problem.  That strongly implies there's something else you haven't specified that's causing the problem.  Without knowing what that is, I can't help you.

Comment: Hi, seems like my cargo command is linked to an older binary. after i properly linked rust and cargo, the issue is resolved with out any edits. Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions of Cargo, if your crate has a name with hyphens, you can directly rely on underscores instead. Cargo gives you this hint actually:

```
error: crate name using dashes are not valid in `extern crate` statements
 --> tests/config.rs:1:14
  |
1 | extern crate my-crate;
  |              ^^^^^^^^ dash-separated idents are not valid
  |
help: if the original crate name uses dashes you need to use underscores in the code
  |
1 | extern crate my_crate;
  |                ~
```